Solving the fundamental solution of the origin of $\Delta u=\Delta_x u+\frac{a}{r}u_r+u_{rr}=0$
The discussion starts from introducing a function $u(x,y):\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^{1+a}\to\mathbb{R}$ is radially symmetric, i.e. for $|y|=|y'|=r$, we have $u(x,y)=u(x,y')$.
I am working on funding a fundamental solution for the following PDE:
$$\Delta u=\Delta_x u+\frac{a}{r}u_r+u_{rr}=0$$
According to the paper from Caff and Silv (2008), the fundamental solution of the origin is
$$\Gamma(X)=C_{n+1+a}\frac{1}{||X||^{n-1+a}}$$
where $X=(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1+a}$ and $C_{n+1+a}=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n+1+a}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{n+1+a}{2}-1)}{4}$.
The paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608640) didn't provide any solution, yet it did mention that how the constant is derived, and I suspect that there is an abuse of notations, as it doesn't make sense that the $\Gamma$ in $\Gamma(\frac{n+1+a}{2}-1)$ is the $\Gamma$ that stands for the fundamental solution of the origin. Therefore, I am seeking help for the clarification.
EDIT:
I use the pdf from @Mason (https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf) Ex 11-13 in p.181
We start with the equation:
$\Delta u = \Delta_x u + \frac{a}{r}u_r + u_{rr} = 0$
This is equivalent to the Laplace equation in $n+1+a$ dimensions.
From Exercise 12, we know that the fundamental solution for the Laplacian in $m$ dimensions ($m \geq 3$) is of the form:
$\Gamma(x) = c_m |x|^{2-m}$
In our case, $m = n+1+a$, so our fundamental solution should be:
$\Gamma(X) = c_{n+1+a} |X|^{-(n-1+a)}$
where $X = (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1+a}$
Now, we need to determine $c_{n+1+a}$. From Exercise 13, we know:
$c_m = \frac{1}{(m-2)A_{m-1}}$
Substituting $m = n+1+a$:
$c_{n+1+a} = \frac{1}{((n+1+a)-2)A_{n+a}}$
Now we use the formula for $A_{m-1}$ from Exercise 11:
$A_{m-1} = \frac{2\pi^{m/2}}{\Gamma(m/2)}$
Substituting $m = n+1+a$:
$A_{n+a} = \frac{2\pi^{(n+1+a)/2}}{\Gamma((n+1+a)/2)}$
Now we can write out the full expression for $c_{n+1+a}$:
$c_{n+1+a} = \frac{1}{(n-1+a)A_{n+a}} = \frac{1}{(n-1+a)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma((n+1+a)/2)}{2\pi^{(n+1+a)/2}}$
Therefore, our fundamental solution is:
$\Gamma(X) = \frac{\Gamma((n+1+a)/2)}{2(n-1+a)\pi^{(n+1+a)/2}} |X|^{-(n-1+a)}$
This is the constant we derive using the theorems from Taylor's book. It differs from the one in the Caffarelli and Silvestre paper mainly in the placement of the Gamma function (in the numerator here, rather than the denominator) and some additional factors.
I believe that the difference likely comes from different normalizations or conventions used in defining the fundamental solution. Hope that clarifies my question.
EDIT 2:
I've encountered a discrepancy in the constant $C_{n+1+a}$ that I can't reconcile.
In a paper I'm reading, the constant is given as:
$$C_{n+1+a}=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n+1+a}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{n+1+a}{2}-1)}{4}$$
However, I've derived a different expression:
$$C_{n+1+a}=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+a+1}{2})}{(n-1+a)\pi^{n/2}\Gamma(\frac{a+1}{2})}$$
Here's my derivation:

Start with the integral equation:
$C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \lim_{y \to 0^+} y^a |X|^{-(n+1+a)}y \, dx = 1$

Express $|X|$ in terms of $x$ and $y$:
$|X| = \sqrt{|x|^2 + y^2}$

Rewrite the integral:
$C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \lim_{y \to 0^+} y^{a+1} (|x|^2 + y^2)^{-(n+1+a)/2} \, dx = 1$

Transform to spherical coordinates:
$C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \omega_n \lim_{y \to 0^+} y^{a+1} \int_0^\infty r^{n-1} (r^2 + y^2)^{-(n+1+a)/2} \, dr = 1$

Evaluate the r-integral:
$\int_0^\infty r^{n-1} (r^2 + y^2)^{-(n+1+a)/2} \, dr = \frac{1}{2} y^{-a-1} B(\frac{n}{2}, \frac{a+1}{2})$

Substitute and simplify:
$C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \omega_n \cdot \frac{1}{2} B(\frac{n}{2}, \frac{a+1}{2}) = 1$

Express Beta function in terms of Gamma functions:
$C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \omega_n \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{a+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n+a+1}{2})} = 1$

Use $\omega_n = \frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}$:
$C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot \frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{a+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n+a+1}{2})} = 1$

Solve for $C_{n+1+a}$:
$C_{n+1+a} = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+a+1}{2})}{(n-1+a)\pi^{n/2}\Gamma(\frac{a+1}{2})}$


These two expressions for $C_{n+1+a}$ appear to be different.
EDIT 3:
Given: $T = \Delta_x + \frac{a}{y}\partial_y + \partial_{yy}$
We want to find $G$ such that $TG = \delta_0$, where $G = C|X|^{-(n+1+a)}$ and $X = (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

I have no problem for verifying that $TG = 0$ for $X \neq 0$.

Now, we need to show that for any test function $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$:
$$\langle TG, f \rangle = \int G(X)T^*f(X) dX = f(0)$$
where $T^*$ is the formal adjoint of $T$.

The formal adjoint $T^*$ is:
$$T^* = \Delta_x - \frac{a}{y}\partial_y + \partial_{yy} + \frac{a}{y^2}$$

We need to evaluate:
$$C \int |X|^{-(n+1+a)} (\Delta_xf - \frac{a}{y}\partial_yf + \partial_{yy}f + \frac{a}{y^2}f) dX = f(0)$$

Using integration by parts and noting that boundary terms vanish due to $f$ having compact support:
$$C \int (\Delta_x|X|^{-(n+1+a)})f + (-\frac{a}{y}\partial_y|X|^{-(n+1+a)} + \partial_{yy}|X|^{-(n+1+a)} + \frac{a}{y^2}|X|^{-(n+1+a)})f dX = f(0)$$

This integral is singular at $X = 0$. We can evaluate it by integrating over $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ minus a small ball around the origin, then take the limit as the ball's radius goes to zero:
$C \lim_{\varepsilon\to0} \int_{|X|>\varepsilon} (...) dX = f(0)$



You can just think of it as $u : \mathbb{R}^{n + 1 + a} \to \mathbb{R}$. The fundamental solution is well known to be proportional to $|x|^{-(n + 1 + a - 2)}$. Derivations can be found in many PDE texts such as those by Folland, Taylor, Jost, Evans. The $\Gamma$ on the RHS is the gamma function. See exercises 11-13 on page 181 of https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf

Sorry can you tell me more on how to use the result of exercises 11-13 in your url to prove the formula of $C_{n+1+a}$? I can't find a complete proof so far.

The formula for the area $A_{n - 1}$ of the sphere $S^{n - 1}$ is proved earlier in the text. It is well known and in many places, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere.

That's exactly my question. If so, the Gamma function should be in the denominator. But the formula of the function is in the nominator.
The paper I referred to is https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608640

In the exercises it is shown that, in your notation, $C_{n} = \frac{1}{(n - 2)A_{n - 1}}$.

I derived the constant using your pdf by Taylor. It still differs from the one in the paper. I edited my post for that. Please have a look.

Their PDE (1.5) is $Tu = 0$,, where $T$ is not the Laplace operator. The connection they make to functions radial in the last variable $y$ is meant to show that $G(X) = \frac{1}{|X|^{n - 1 + a}}$ satisfies (1.5) away from $0$, and then it is up to you to get the right $C_{n + 1 + a}$ to achieve $TG = -\delta_0$.

Thank you for your help, but I'm still having some trouble deriving the constant. The constant I've calculated is:
$C_{n+1+a} = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+a+1}{2})}{(n-1+a)\pi^{n/2}\Gamma(\frac{a+1}{2})}$
However, the one given in the paper is:
$C_{n+1+a}=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n+1+a}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{n+1+a}{2}-1)}{4}$
I've included my derivation in Edit 2 of my original post. Could you please take a look and help me understand where the discrepancy might be coming from?

It's not obvious to me why the integral equation you write in 1 is equivalent to $TG = -\delta_0$.

The term
$\lim_{y\to 0^+}y^a\partial_y(C_{n+1+a}G)$
$=-C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)\lim_{y\to 0^+}y^a|X|^{-(n+1+a)}y$
represents $-\delta_0$. So the negative sign canceled out, and hence we have
$C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\lim_{y\to 0^+}y^a|X|^{-(n+1+a)}ydx=1$

I'm not sure why that term you wrote is $-\delta_0$. I might be missing some context, but I didn't see a derivation in the paper. The derivation of that part would give me some insight; I feel like if you know that this term is $-C\delta_0$, then wouldn't you have found $C$ in the process of proving this?

Oh, I think I see your point now. But then what is the general setup for finding the $C_{n+1+a}$? Seems I lack information for the setup then.

Write the PDE (1.5) as $Tu = 0$, where $T$ is a second order differential operator. The fundamental solution $G$ is supposed to satisfy $TG = \delta_0$. This means that $TG(X) = 0$ for $X \neq 0$ and that for any $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$, $$\langle TG, f \rangle = \int G(X) T^{}f(X),dX = f(0),$$ where $T^{}$ is the formal adjoint of $T$. I envisioned computing this integral like Taylor did using integration by parts to show $G = C|X|^{-(n - 1 + a)}$ works and to find $C$. The only thing clear to me from the paper is that $T|X|^{-(n - 1 + a)} = 0$ for $X \neq 0$.

I made an EDIT 3 in my post. Can you help me have a look? After the step 5 in my EDIT 3, I am going to integrate over $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ minus a small ball around the origin, then take the limit as the ball's radius goes to zero, to deal with the removable singularity at the origin:
$C \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \int_{|X|>\varepsilon} (...) dX = f(0)$

After that, do I directly apply the divergence theorem? Seems there is no dominant term as $\varepsilon\to 0$ as every terms behaves like $|X|^{-(n+3+a)}$ near the origin.

I haven't done the computation myself, but hopefully it should be similar to the exercises in M. Taylor's book.

To make our progress so far to be clearer, I made an answer (partially) down below, But I stuck then

Part 1

We want to show that $T\Gamma(X) = 0$ for $X \neq 0$, where $\Gamma(X) = C_{n+1+a} |X|^{-(n-1+a)}$ and $T$ is the operator defined in equation (1.5) of the paper:
$$T = \Delta_x + \frac{a}{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$$
Let's break this down:
We write out $\Gamma(X)$ explicitly:
$$\Gamma(X) = C_{n+1+a} (x_1^2 + x_2^2 + ... + x_n^2 + y^2)^{-\frac{n-1+a}{2}}$$
For each $i = 1, ..., n$:
$$\begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial x_i} &= C_{n+1+a} \cdot (-\frac{n-1+a}{2}) \cdot (x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2 + y^2)^{-\frac{n+1+a}{2}} \cdot 2x_i \\
  &= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot x_i \cdot (x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2 + y^2)^{-\frac{n+1+a}{2}}\\
  &= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot x_i \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)}\\
  \end{align*}$$
Now, let's compute the second derivative:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 \Gamma}{\partial x_i^2} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left(-C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot x_i \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)}\right) \\[10pt]
&= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left(x_i \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)}\right) \\[10pt]
&= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot \left(|X|^{-(n+1+a)} + x_i \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(|X|^{-(n+1+a)})\right) \\[10pt]
&= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)} \\
&\quad -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot x_i \cdot (-(n+1+a)) \cdot |X|^{-(n+2+a)} \cdot \frac{\partial |X|}{\partial x_i} \\[10pt]
&= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)} \\
&\quad +C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)(n+1+a) \cdot x_i \cdot |X|^{-(n+2+a)} \cdot \frac{x_i}{|X|} \\[10pt]
&= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)} \\
&\quad +C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)(n+1+a) \cdot x_i^2 \cdot |X|^{-(n+3+a)}
\end{align*}$$
Here, I used the fact that $\frac{\partial |X|}{\partial x_i} = \frac{x_i}{|X|}$.
Now, we sum this over all $i$ from 1 to $n$:
$$\begin{align*}
\Delta_x \Gamma &= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 \Gamma}{\partial x_i^2} \\[10pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left(-C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)}\right) \\
&\quad + \sum_{i=1}^n \left(C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)(n+1+a) \cdot x_i^2 \cdot |X|^{-(n+3+a)}\right) \\[10pt]
&= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)} \cdot n \\
&\quad + C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)(n+1+a) \cdot |X|^{-(n+3+a)} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \\[10pt]
&= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)n \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)} \\
&\quad + C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)(n+1+a) \cdot (x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2) \cdot |X|^{-(n+3+a)}\\
&\quad + C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)(n+1+a) \cdot |x|^2 \cdot |X|^{-(n+3+a)}\\
\end{align*}$$
Similarly,
$$\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial y}= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot y \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)}$$
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{a}{y}\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial y} &= \frac{a}{y} \cdot \left(-C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot y \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)}\right) \\[10pt]
&= -aC_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)}
\end{align*}$$
Also,
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 \Gamma}{\partial y^2} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(-C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot y \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)}\right) \\[10pt]
&= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(y \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)}\right) \\[10pt]
&= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot \left(|X|^{-(n+1+a)} + y \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(|X|^{-(n+1+a)})\right) \\[10pt]
&= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)} \\
&\quad -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot y \cdot (-(n+1+a)) \cdot |X|^{-(n+2+a)} \cdot \frac{\partial |X|}{\partial y} \\[10pt]
&= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)} \\
&\quad -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot y \cdot (-(n+1+a)) \cdot |X|^{-(n+2+a)} \cdot \frac{y}{|X|} \\[10pt]
&= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)} \\
&\quad +C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)(n+1+a) \cdot y^2 \cdot |X|^{-(n+3+a)}
\end{align*}$$
Now, let's add all these terms to get TΓ:
$$\begin{align*}
T\Gamma &= \Delta_x \Gamma + \frac{a}{y}\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial^2 \Gamma}{\partial y^2} \\[10pt]
&= [-C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)n - aC_{n+1+a}(n-1+a) - C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)] \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)} \\
&\quad + C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)(n+1+a) \cdot (x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2 + y^2) \cdot |X|^{-(n+3+a)} \\[10pt]
&= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)(n+1+a) \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)} \\
&\quad + C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)(n+1+a) \cdot |X|^2 \cdot |X|^{-(n+3+a)} \\[10pt]
&= -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)(n+1+a) \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)} \\
&\quad + C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)(n+1+a) \cdot |X|^{-(n+1+a)} \\[10pt]
&= 0
\end{align*}$$
Therefore, we have shown that TΓ = 0 for X ≠ 0.
Hence, Γ satisfies equation (1.5) away from the origin, as stated in the paper.
Part 2

We have the operator $T = \Delta_x + \frac{a}{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$.
To find the formal adjoint $T^*$, we need to use integration by parts on each term. Let's consider a smooth, compactly supported function $f$ and another function $u$ (which will eventually be our $\Gamma$).
For the Laplacian term:
$$\begin{aligned}
   \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} u \Delta_x f \, dX &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_0^\infty u \Delta_x f \, dy \, dx \\
   &= \int_0^\infty \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u \Delta_x f \, dx\right) \, dy \\
   &= \int_0^\infty \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f \Delta_x u \, dx\right) \, dy \quad \text{(by Green's second identity)}\\
   &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} f \Delta_x u \, dX
   \end{aligned}$$
For the $\frac{a}{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ term:
First, recall the definition of the adjoint operator. For operators A and A*, and suitable test functions f and g, we have:
$\langle Af, g \rangle = \langle f, A^*g \rangle$
where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the inner product.
In our case, A = $\frac{a}{y}\partial_y$, where a is a constant. We need to find A*.
Let's consider the left side of the equation:
$\langle \frac{a}{y}\partial_y f, g \rangle = \int_0^\infty \frac{a}{y}\partial_y f(y) \cdot g(y) dy$
Now, let's use integration by parts. The formula is:
$\int u dv = uv - \int v du$
Here, $u = f(y)$, $dv = \frac{a}{y}g(y)dy$
Applying integration by parts:
$\int_0^\infty \frac{a}{y}\partial_y f(y) \cdot g(y) dy = [af(y)\frac{g(y)}{y}]_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty f(y) \cdot \partial_y(\frac{a}{y}g(y)) dy$
The boundary term $[af(y)\frac{g(y)}{y}]_0^\infty$ vanishes because f and g are test functions (they have compact support).
Now, let's focus on $\partial_y(\frac{a}{y}g(y))$:
$\partial_y(\frac{a}{y}g(y)) = \frac{a}{y}\partial_y g(y) - \frac{a}{y^2}g(y)$
Substituting this back into our integral:
$-\int_0^\infty f(y) \cdot (\frac{a}{y}\partial_y g(y) - \frac{a}{y^2}g(y)) dy$
This can be rewritten as:
$\int_0^\infty f(y) \cdot (-\frac{a}{y}\partial_y g(y) + \frac{a}{y^2}g(y)) dy$
Comparing this with the definition of the adjoint operator, we can conclude:
$(\frac{a}{y}\partial_y)^* = -\frac{a}{y}\partial_y + \frac{a}{y^2}$
Thus, we have shown that $(\frac{a}{y}\partial_y)^* = -\frac{a}{y}\partial_y + \frac{a}{y^2}$.
For the $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$ term:
$$\begin{aligned}
   \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} u \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \, dX &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_0^\infty u \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \, dy \, dx \\
   &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left[u\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right]_0^\infty - \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \, dy \, dx \\
   &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left[u\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - f\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right]_0^\infty + \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_0^\infty f \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} \, dy \, dx \\
   &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} f \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} \, dX
   \end{aligned}$$
Again, the boundary terms vanish due to the compact support of $f$.
Combining these results, we get:
$$\begin{aligned}
   \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} u Tf \, dX &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} f \left(\Delta_x u - \frac{a}{y}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}\right) \, dX \\
   &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} f T^*u \, dX
   \end{aligned}$$
where $T^* = \Delta_x - \frac{a}{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \frac{a}{y^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$

Now, to compute $\langle T\Gamma, f \rangle$, we use the definition of distributional derivative:
$$\langle T\Gamma, f \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \Gamma(X) T^*f(X) \, dX$$
Substituting $\Gamma(X) = C_{n+1+a} \frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}}$, we get:
$$\langle T\Gamma, f \rangle = C_{n+1+a} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}} T^*f(X) \, dX$$
We set that:
$$\langle T\Gamma, f \rangle = C_{n+1+a} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}} T^*f(X) \, dX = f(0)$$
for all test functions f.
We start with:
$$\langle T\Gamma, f \rangle = C_{n+1+a} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}} T^*f(X) \, dX$$
Then,
$$\langle T\Gamma, f \rangle = C_{n+1+a} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}} (\Delta_x f - \frac{a}{y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{a}{y^2}f + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}) \, dX$$
Now, let's integrate by parts for each term:
For $\Delta_x f$:
Let's start with the general form of integration by parts in multiple dimensions:
$$\int_\Omega u \Delta v \, dX = \int_{\partial\Omega} u \frac{\partial v}{\partial n} \, dS - \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, dX$$
Here, $u = f$ and $v = \frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}}$. We're integrating over all of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, so the boundary term vanishes:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} f \Delta_x (\frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}}) \, dX = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \nabla_x f \cdot \nabla_x (\frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}}) \, dX$$
Now we apply integration by parts again to the right-hand side:
$$- \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \nabla_x f \cdot \nabla_x (\frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}}) \, dX = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} f \Delta_x (\frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}}) \, dX$$
Then,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}} \Delta_x f \, dX = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} f \Delta_x (\frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}}) \, dX$$
For $-\frac{a}{y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$:
We use the one-dimensional integration by parts formula:
$$\int uv' \, dy = uv|_{\text{boundary}} - \int u'v \, dy$$
Here, $u = f$, $v' = -\frac{a}{y|X|^{n-1+a}}$. The boundary term vanishes as we integrate over all of $\mathbb{R}$:
$$-\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}} \frac{a}{y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \, dX = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} f \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{a}{y|X|^{n-1+a}}) \, dX$$
Then,
$$-\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}} \frac{a}{y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \, dX = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} f \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{a}{y|X|^{n-1+a}}) \, dX$$
For $\frac{a}{y^2}f$, no integration by parts is needed.
For $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}$:
We apply integration by parts twice. First:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \, dX = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}}) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \, dX$$
Then we apply it again:
$$-\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}}) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \, dX = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} f \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}(\frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}}) \, dX$$
Then,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \, dX = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} f \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}(\frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}}) \, dX$$
Combining all these terms:
$$\langle T\Gamma, f \rangle = C_{n+1+a} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} f(X) [\Delta_x (\frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}}) + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{a}{y|X|^{n-1+a}}) + \frac{a}{y^2|X|^{n-1+a}} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}(\frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}})] \, dX$$
For this to equal $f(0)$ for all test functions $f$, the term in square brackets must equal a delta function at the origin. In other words:
$$C_{n+1+a} [\Delta_x (\frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}}) + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{a}{y|X|^{n-1+a}}) + \frac{a}{y^2|X|^{n-1+a}} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}(\frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}})] = \delta_0(X)$$

Let $G(X) = C_{n+1+a}|X|^{-(n-1+a)}$.
Combining all terms from the previous steps:
$\int_{D_\varepsilon} T^*f(X)G(X)\,dX = \int_{D_\varepsilon} f(X)TG(X)\,dX + \text{Boundary Terms}$
The boundary terms are:
$\int_{\partial D_\varepsilon} [(f\frac{\partial G}{\partial n} - G\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}) - \frac{a}{y}fG - (f\frac{\partial G}{\partial y} - G\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})] \,dS$
Since $TG = 0$, the volume integral vanishes, leaving only the boundary terms:
$\langle f,TG\rangle = \lim_{\varepsilon\to0} \int_{\partial D_\varepsilon} [(f\frac{\partial G}{\partial n} - G\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}) - \frac{a}{y}fG - (f\frac{\partial G}{\partial y} - G\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})] \,dS$
Now, let's evaluate these boundary terms in more detail:
First, note that on $\partial D_\varepsilon$, we have $|X| = \varepsilon$, so $G = C_{n+1+a}\varepsilon^{-(n-1+a)}$.
The normal derivative $\frac{\partial G}{\partial n}$ on $\partial D_\varepsilon$:
$\frac{\partial G}{\partial n} = -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)\varepsilon^{-(n+a)}$
The y-derivative of G:
$\frac{\partial G}{\partial y} = C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)\frac{y}{\varepsilon^{n+1+a}}$
Substituting these into our boundary integral:
$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \int_{\partial D_\varepsilon} [f(-C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)\varepsilon^{-(n+a)}) - C_{n+1+a}\varepsilon^{-(n-1+a)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial n} - \frac{a}{y}fC_{n+1+a}\varepsilon^{-(n-1+a)} - (fC_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)\frac{y}{\varepsilon^{n+1+a}} - C_{n+1+a}\varepsilon^{-(n-1+a)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})] \,dS$
As $\varepsilon \to 0$, $f(X)$ and its derivatives approach their values at the origin. Let's denote $f(0)$ as $f_0$, $\nabla f(0)$ as $\nabla f_0$, etc. The integral becomes:
$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0} C_{n+1+a}\varepsilon^{-(n-1+a)} \int_{\partial D_\varepsilon} [-(n-1+a)f_0\varepsilon^{-1} - \nabla f_0 \cdot \hat{n} - \frac{a}{y}f_0 - (n-1+a)f_0\frac{y}{\varepsilon^2} + \frac{\partial f_0}{\partial y}] \,dS$
The surface element $dS$ on $\partial D_\varepsilon$ is proportional to $\varepsilon^n$. The integral of $\hat{n}$ over the sphere is zero, and the integral of $\frac{y}{\varepsilon}$ is also zero due to symmetry. The remaining terms give:
$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0} C_{n+1+a}\varepsilon^{-(n-1+a)} \cdot \varepsilon^n \cdot [-\frac{n-1+a}{\varepsilon}f_0 \cdot |\partial D_\varepsilon|]$
where $|\partial D_\varepsilon|$ is the surface area of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, which is $\frac{2\pi^{(n+1)/2}}{\Gamma((n+1)/2)}$.
Simplifying:
$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0} -C_{n+1+a}(n-1+a)f_0 \cdot \frac{2\pi^{(n+1)/2}}{\Gamma((n+1)/2)}$
For this to equal $f_0$ for all test functions $f$, we must have:
$C_{n+1+a} = -\frac{\Gamma((n+1)/2)}{(n-1+a)2\pi^{(n+1)/2}}$

For this problem, we should regard $T$ as a distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n \times (0, \infty)$, so we regard the test functions as $f \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n \times (0, \infty))$. Your $T^$ is wrong. I got $(\frac{a}{y}\partial_{y})^{} = -\frac{a}{y}\partial_{y} + \frac{a}{y^2}$, so $$T^* = \Delta_{x} - \frac{a}{y}\partial_{y} + \frac{a}{y^2} + \partial_{y}^2.$$

Next, to cleanly carry out the computation of $$\langle f, TG \rangle = \int T^{}f(X) G(X),dX = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_{B_{\varepsilon}^c} T^{}f(X) G(X),dX,$$ for some well chosen sets $B_{\varepsilon}$, what we want to do is to integrate by parts to move the $T^*$ over to a $T$ on the $G$ because $TG = 0$. What will happen is that all we will get are boundary terms incurred by applying the integration by parts $$\int_{\Omega}\partial_{x_j}g h ,dX = -\int_{\Omega}g \partial_{x_j}h ,dX + \int_{\partial \Omega} g h N_j ,dS.$$

@Mason I updated my answer, not sure is it your idea, but the constant is still weird, not in the form and not even equal to the constant stated in the paper.
